# How can I use Python Google API without getting a fresh auth code via browser each time?

Tags: google-api

I am playing with the Google API. I am using [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) as a starting point, [here](https://pastebin.com/GHYtUdwM) is the actual Python code.

I have created a OAuth 2.0 client ID at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and downloaded it as `client_secret.json` which is used in the code as follows:

```
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"

def get_authenticated_service():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_console()
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)
```

The contents of `client_secret.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "**REDACTED**",
    "project_id": "api-project-1014650230452",
    "auth_uri": "https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/o\/oauth2\/auth",
    "token_uri": "https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/o\/oauth2\/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/oauth2\/v1\/certs",
    "client_secret": "**REDACTED**",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
      "http:\/\/localhost"
    ]
  }
}
```

The whole program works and successfully returns a meaningful data set, however, each time I run the program I am prompted as follows:

> ```
> Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=...
> Enter the authorization code:
> ```

I enter the code and the program works, but I have to visit this URL and get a fresh code each time the program runs. I was under the impression that `client_secret.json` existed precisely to prevent this from being necessary.

What do I have to do to make my CLI Python program use the API without having to get a fresh token each time?

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Yes, this works as an answer. I'm not entirely satisfied because it seems like a hack, and because it seems like the client secrets file should be the sort of thing which does this, which means I/we may still not be doing it The Right Way. But it works. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Although I'm not sure whether I can correctly understand about your situation, how about using Service Accounts? The document is [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts). If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to run the script without retrieving the code every time. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, when the script is run for the first time, the refresh token is saved to a file of "credential_sample.json". By this, from the next run, you can use the API using the access token retrieved by the refresh token. So you are not required to retrieve the code every time.

#### Modified script :

Please modify as follows.

From :

```
def get_authenticated_service():
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)
```

To :

```
from oauth2client import client # Added
from oauth2client import tools # Added
from oauth2client.file import Storage # Added

def get_authenticated_service(): # Modified
    credential_path = os.path.join('./', 'credential_sample.json')
    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)
```

#### Note :

- When you run this for the first time, the browser is automatically opened. When you authorize the scopes, the script automatically retrieves the code and create the tokens to "credential_sample.json".
- This modification supposes that your current script works except for being required to retrieve the code every time.

#### References :

- [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

  - About this modification, you can also refer this script.

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

After playing with a bunch of solutions, including the accepted answer, here's mine:

```
def get_authenticated_service():
    try:
        credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE)
    except ValueError as e: # first run with new secret.json (no refresh_token yet)
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
        credentials = flow.run_console()
        with open(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, 'w') as file:
            file.write(credentials.to_json())
    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)
```