# Youtube API V3 playlistItems batch adding error

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, youtube-api, batch-processing

I am trying to add a bunch of songs into a pre-created playlist using Python and Youtube API. I got my code working, but it only added 9 or 11 / 32 songs I had. I have no idea why I failed to add these songs. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.playlistItems.insert
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

videoIds = ['n6Pnzi6r9NU',
 'PYuE2roIkH0',
 'NfTS7gM7zQ0',
 'dvgZkm1xWPE',
 'LZN4I3K8SC0',
 'ihnzsr9yUEI',
 'SGlBQR-ftVI',
 'ZqxnPLICfeg',
 'Ut32pLNe-lM',
 '4OtcskeRBJw',
 'WFBuC2JDon8',
 'P196hEuA_Xc',
 'gDT7d6CjKKs',
 'i6DGSIKEuF8',
 'K_iH2YSaY3U',
 'WJZcNMGIbiE',
 '_2quiyHfJQw',
 'UM3389FUnKo',
 'b8OELzmpgZo',
 'Cl8a9b76GMg',
 'aKg9LZX9Vl4',
 'rLHqnOq4wEQ',
 '4u-ejGIxPqo',
 'dT2owtxkU8k',
 'redFrGBZoJY',
 'z6yO3CnN4L0',
 'piOIvNO2M8Q',
 'x1YkHJJi-tc',
 'sVZpHFXcFJw',
 '399YneFTwh0',
 'Xdv83MFJd7U']

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "some_json_API_files"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
    batch = youtube.new_batch_http_request()
    
    for videoId in videoIds:
        batch.add(youtube.playlistItems().insert(
            part="snippet",
            body={
                "snippet": {
                "playlistId": "a_playlist_id",
                "position": 0,
                "resourceId": {
                    "kind": "youtube#video",
                    "videoId": videoId
            }
          }
        }
      )
    )
    responses = batch.execute()

    print(responses)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When checking API dashboard, I saw youtube.api.v3.V3DataPlaylistItemService.Insert had the percentage of errors is 56% with 220 requests. Is this normal and how can I batch adding my songs into youtube playlist. This is the output I got :

```
F:\another damn proj>py example1.py
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=645563229764-vp144utnb3qnuvexxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.force-ssl&state=xxxxx
Enter the authorization code: 4/1AY0e-g5-uRPey7zmxxNm2I2rF8IfJcCWInb4n6Lha4YC_8qyBacEGeso1No
None
```

I just can't figure what is "None" and why there are so many error requests.

Comment: please edit your question and include the error.

Comment: Fixed the question already.

Comment: @Teebowie `Please visit this URL to authorize this application` = did you follow those instructions? - I admit I don't know about python, but, a quick search on Google using the search term: `Please visit this URL to authorize this application` retrieves this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51488102/12511801) - it might help in your scenario.

Comment: Yes, I already done that. Some videos had already been added to the playlist.